# Custom Columns in Thunar

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, file-manager, thunar

When viewing files in [`thunar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar).

I'd like to have columns with different information than the ones available in the Configure Columns dialog. For example, if I have a .mp3,

I'd like to have columns showing the track number, album name, artist, etc. I understand it's possible to show this with a custom action and a pop-up, but I'd prefer to have the tag information in a column to keep it visible and allow sorting. If this isn't possible in [`thunar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar), recommendations of other file managers with this capability are welcome.

Comment: I was looking for the same. In fact I tried many other file managers also. It's astounding that such a simple thing is not available in any file manager!